# Is there any thought experiment that has proof?

Tags: terminology, thought-experiment

Is there any [thought experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thought_experiment) that are proved mathematically? Or is it thought experiments are all pure hypothesis?

Comment: can you share with us what you have found out about this in your own research?

Comment: @Steeven I am sorry that my understanding of the subject is very limited, I came to know about thought experiments after reading about Schrödinger's cat, Maxwell's demon

Answer (score 4):

Despite the name, "thought experiments" are theory, not experiment.

And they are as much about *communicating* theory as they are about understanding theory.

They are a tool for clarifying the implications of a theory by setting up (carefully and clearly) a situation that isolates one prediction of a theory from confounding factors. And that set-up more or less requires that you understand the theory before you being, which is why I say they are about communication.

The implication of this is that any evidence you have is supportive of or contradictory to the theory you used in build your "experiment" rather than being about the "experiment" as such.

Comment: Would you say running simulations in a mental sandbox fall under thought experiments or belong to a different classification? If the latter, what specifically?

Answer (score 2):

What is a thought experiment for you? Is it a scientist sitting down and thinking up a theory? Maybe he saw some behavior or phenomenon in the physical World and he is now thinking it to its logical conclusion and consequence?

Then, yes, many (all?) physical theories start like that and are then empirically / experimentally proved or disproved. You theorize how something will work in general based on a few findings and observations and then you test, test, test until you trust that theory to be true - or until you refute or alter it.

Newton's laws, the laws of thermodynamics, the models of the atom, relativity, friction models etc. are all theories that are in consensus and fully established, while theories of quantum behavior, Higgs boson influence on gravity, the Big Bang and its origin, certain astronomical unexplained events etc. still are in the process.

The **proof** for such thought-experiment (such theory) will in these cases be purely empirical and experimental (statistical, you could say in some cases). In other words: Such theories can't be proven rigorously; but if you after a thousand experiments and after a thousand people's experiments can't refute it - if you can't find just one counter-example - then you might start trusting this theory to be the truth. This is the method of [falsification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability).